# Wikipedia Dump into MySQL database - only a part of database

Tags: java, sql, database, dump, wikipedia

I imported some Wikipedia dump file in a sql database. Everything worked fine. Except the fact that only a part of 3 GB dump is imported into the database (only 1000 articles, with articles beginning with an a to z). What is the problem?
Using http://alexpb.com/notes/articles/2007/09/25/importing-wikimedia-dump-file-to-mysql/

Thanks :)

Comment: Kindly provide the actual objective

Comment: My goal is to import the whole database into sql database, not only a part of it.

Comment: are you sure your database has enough space to store it all?

Comment: @Jeremy C. How can I controll that?

Answer (score 1):

MWDumper is severely unmaintained, try [importDump.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ImportDump.php)